# How can I save my multiple tabs session in an xfce4-terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, xfce, session

So I usually have tons of tabs open in terminal sessions and every time I open a new terminal I have to manually open up all tabs. This is pretty annoying.

I checked `man xfce4-terminal` but it didn't say anything about saving a session. Is this possible?

Comment: An alternative would be to create a custom launcher that opens all the tabs with places that you wanted. This assumes you always want the same locations

Comment: That sounds doable. How would I do that? Would you happen to know any howtos/tutorials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create  a shortcut with pre-defined tabs like this:

```
Terminal --geometry=100x40 --hide-menubar --hide-toolbars -T "Host1" -e "ssh -t root@host1" --tab -T "Host2" -e "ssh -t root@host2"
```

But something like that in the Command line of the shortcut editor dialog.

To have each tab have a different working directory you can do it this way:

```
Terminal --working-directory=$HOME/tmp --tab --working-directory=$HOME/src --tab --working-directory=$HOME/opt
```

Not that the first one doesn't have a `--tab` before it, making it associate with the new top-level window. Then two additional tabs with different working directories.

Try to avoid using `~` expansion, as that is a shell feature that may not work in other context (such as custom launchers).

Comment: How could I open one new terminal window with let's say three tabs showing three different directories (~/myuser/code, ~/myuser/logs, ~/myuser/backup)? Perhaps I have misunderstood the meaning of `working-directory`, but I thought that would do the trick but I can't get it to work...

Comment: Thanks much for the edit. Turns out `$HOME` was the piece I was missing, works as advertised now.

Answer (score 4):

This solution deploys one window with multiple tabs and processes.

I created a startup script (`xfce4-terminal-startup.sh`),

```
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-terminal --maximize --title='Neovim' -x bash -c "nvr -s; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='psql' -x bash -c "psql -d zzz; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='Cypher-shell' -x bash -c "cd /mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/hmdb; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='Cycli' -x bash -c "source activate py35 && cycli -P *** -u *** -p ***; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='Py3' -x bash -c "source activate py35 && python; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='bc' -x bash -c "bc; exec bash"
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='ud' -x bash -c "pacaur -Syu; exec bash"
```

that when executed starts xfce4-terminal, maximizes it, and launches the various programs as indicated.

Regarding "exec bash", above see:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends
  *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/how-to-run-xfce-terminal-with-different-commands-per-tab-and-keep-using-the-tabs

I.e.: if you start a window in screen that runs a command, keep that window open ...

---

Here is an animated GIF, showing those tabs in action!

[image: xfce4-terminal from script with tabs, programs preloaded]

[[link to larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU3GK.gif)]

---

- **Reference:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/421421/how-can-i-make-a-terminal-with-3-tabs-appear-after-startup/422121#422121

---

**Update**

This is my current `xfce4-terminal-startup.sh` script (you can download it here: https://persagen.com/files/misc/xfce4-terminal-startup.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
# vim: set filetype=sh :
# vim: syntax=sh

# /mnt/Vancouver/programming/scripts/xfce4-terminal-startup.sh

# https://web.archive.org/web/20110314180918/http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870992/automatic-exit-from-bash-shell-script-on-error/2871034#2871034
set -e

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This one first:

# Python as basic calculator: 1/3; import math; 2*math.pi; ...
xfce4-terminal --maximize --title='calculations' -x bash -c "python; exec bash"

# ... then (these will open as child tabs in the parent terminal window, above):

# Open my (current) project directory:
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='bash'  -x bash -c "cd /mnt/Vancouver/projects/ie/claws/; pwd; ls -l; echo ''; exec bash"

# Start Neovim:
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='neovim' -x bash -c "nvr -s; exec bash"

# Open ripgrep tab (echo sample command), for fast searches in that director:
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='ripgrep' -x bash -c "cd /mnt/Vancouver/domains/PERSAGEN.com/2.0/; echo rg . -i -e \'1903.03243\'; exec bash"

# Open an Arch Linux update tab:
xfce4-terminal --tab --title='ud' -x bash -c "yay -Syu; exec bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

An xfce4-terminal patched by #OldCoder for #Laclin allows for any number of named tabs to be saved/loaded using the menu. It saves a "TabSet" (up to 4): the working directory and tab name rather than session data itself, but it's enough for me and your post indicates the feature may be enough for you. I had this issue and mentioned it to him since the solution here wasn't satisfactory and he based it on an old patch but got the code working on a recent version.

The web page for the patch is: https://laclin.com/xfce4-tabset.html

With his help I made an install script that does the patching and dependency installation at the following raw download link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/poikilos/linux-preinstall/master/everyone/xfce/xfce4-terminal-laclin_savetabs.sh)

- My script installs most/all dependencies, but you must first install build tools for linux yourself (such as via `sudo apt-get install build-essential` if using Ubuntu/Debian/Devuan and build).
- Save the script such as `wget -O xfce4-terminal-laclin_savetabs.sh` followed by the raw URL above then run in terminal: `bash xfce4-terminal-laclin_savetabs.sh` (it uses sudo for dependencies and for `sudo make install` which results in /usr/local/bin/xfce4-terminal if successful).
- If it says anything is missing, please report the issue here: https://github.com/poikilos/linux-preinstall/issues.